# Why pipenv shell does not get recognized

Tags: python, docker

I have a Dockerfile with the following content:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic AS os
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip \
    && cd /usr/local/bin \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 python \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install pipenv \
    && apt-get install -y curl \ 
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt update \
    && apt install yarn

RUN git clone https://gitlab.com/silentdata/cdtc-identity-service.git
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
WORKDIR /cdtc-identity-service
RUN pipenv --python 3.7
RUN pipenv install
RUN pipenv shell
```

During the image build process, I've got:

```
Step 9/9 : RUN pipenv shell
 ---> Running in a087d2296eb8
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 390, in shell
    pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2184, in do_shell
    shell.fork_compat(*fork_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/shells.py", line 121, in fork_compat
    c.interact(escape_character=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 761, in interact
    mode = tty.tcgetattr(self.STDIN_FILENO)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt you can use `pipenv shell` when you don't have a TTY (especially as it's an interactive command). If you need to run commands within a pipenv environment use `pipenv run <your_command>`

Comment: I second @AlastairMcCormack, and add that if you want to run interactive commands inside the docker container, you need to run `docker run -it docker_image_name /command/`

Answer (score 0):

`pipenv shell` is for interactive use, so doesn't make sense to use in a `Dockerfile`. It's probably erroring because there's no TTY available during a `docker build`.

If you need to run Python commands within your virtual environment during build, use:

```
pipenv run <command_name>
```

E.g.

```
pipenv run python myscript.py
```